# Regex multiline match

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match, multiline

I have a string that contains arbitrary number of `"\n"`. I need to know whether there is a line in the string that does not match a certain pattern. If all lines match the pattern, the return should be `true`. If not, the return should be `false`. The pattern is: word, colon, and digits (`/[\w]+\:[\d]+/`). The code should be in ruby.

These examples are entered by the user in a textarea box on a webpage.
Examples of input content are:

#### A valid example (all lines are valid):

```
something:1
other:2    
more:3
```

#### An invalid example (lines 2,3,4 are invalid -> only lines 1, 5 are valid):

```
something:1     
other:stuff      
invalid         
)/&invalid again 
valid_again:4
```

These examples are received in-code as a single string, lines separated by `\n` (from valid example):

```
valid_example_string = "something:1\nother:2\nmore:3"
```

Is there a simple regex way to do this? I am not looking on how to loop through the lines. I am looking for a shorthand regex way (if it's possible) to match the example, something in the lines of (pseudocode):

```
valid_example_string.test(/the_needed_regex/)    # => true
invalid_example_string.test(/the_needed_regex/)  # => false
```

What's the most simple/elegant/efficient way to do this?

Comment: `something:1` Is it valid or not?

Comment: I don't understand... Does your string contain newlines `\n` or escaped newlines `\\n`? How would it print if you did a `.inspect`?

Comment: Do you just have to check the format or are you processing / converting the string?

Comment: Updated the example. user3218114: it's valid. arco444: added example back again, it was for some reason moved by the user 'sawa'... Stefan: I want to check the format -> user input must match the regex

Comment: To the user 'sawa' who edited the question and removed half of it: if you want to clean it up, that's fine. Just do NOT remove examples that clarify the situation, like the one arco444 asked...

Comment: Are blank lines OK? Might there be a carriage return (`\r`)?

Comment: Blank lines are not OK since the string is eventually processed line-by-line, so the validation should be a oneliner preferably. The validations CAN be processed in the line-by-line loop, but for this purpose, they are not. The \r is a good point and should probably be taken into account, though I have yet to see ruby/our framework output \r or \r\n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a whole-string regex, you can use

```
regex = /\A(\w+:\d+\s*\n?)+\z/
```

### A simple solution

```
!!string.match(regex)
```

The `!!` forces the answer to a boolean `true` or `false`.

### Implementing your pseudocode exactly

You can monkey-patch the String class to add your `test` method:

```
class String
   def test(regex)
     !!self.match(regex)
   end
end
```

Output:

```
valid_example_string.test(regex)    # => true
invalid_example_string.test(regex)  # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

[`lines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-lines) will split a string into lines.
[`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) will return false if the block returns false for any elements.

```
regex = /^\w+\:\d+$/ 
example_string.lines.any?{|e| e =~ regex }
```

Comment: A very good runner-up, and it keeps the regex more simple on a line-by-line basis. Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp = %r{\A(\w+:\d+\n?)*\z} # or %r{\A(\w+:\d+\n?)+\z} to fail on empty strings
valid_example =~ regexp # => 0
invalid_example =~ regexp # => nil
```